# How many days to respond after phone interview

Tags: interviewing, software-industry, internship

I had an interview; it went well. We discussed the position and job I would be doing and the company in general. We spoke for about 50 minutes. I haven't heard anything from them in three days; should I still expect a response?

Comment: sometimes you don't hear for up to 2 weeks after an interview. I wouldn't worry about it. That being said, some companies are fast and you will have the offer emailed to you by the time you hang up the phone(happened to me :) ). If you are worried (you shouldn't be) you can ask others (if you know any) that have applied to the company to see what the typical turn around speed is for an offer (rejections may get no reply....sadly this still happens).

Comment: Just keep applying to jobs, don't wait on just one company to respond!

Comment: If you didn't get the job chances are low you will ever hear from them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer applies to phone interviews, but could just as easily work for face-to-face interviews.

First, if you haven't already, send a thank you note.  Make sure they know you're interested in the position by telling them explicitly.  For other interviews, always send a thank you note right after the interview.

In general, you follow-up a week after your last interaction.  Even if they say something like, "We'll let you know in a couple of days."  People get busy; hiring decisions can take a lot of time.  If you don't continue to let them know your interest, they may think you've lost interest.

Keep following up about once a week.  If they don't respond at all to a phone call or e-mail, it's okay to keep going for several weeks.  Seriously, there's often lots going on that they may not have gotten to a decision on next steps.  Until you're told "no," you do not know you're excluded.

Comment: repeated followups are generally a bad idea. They make hiring officals mad at teh time wasted. Never followup more than once.

Answer (score 1):

One of the most difficult things for most of us to do is to wait when things are out of our control.  As people communicate more and more electronically, our expectations of time periods are different. HR and accounting organizations rarely respond at the speed of Twitter.

I would not EXPECT a response, but it is also very possible that you WILL get a response.  It could come today, or not until the hiring manager is back from a four day trip to X, or when the budget for this position is finalized at the end of the week, etc. for example.

Hiring is sometimes done in a hurry, but the other current obligations of an organization usually trump return calls when push comes to shove.

One of the other important things to remember is that a phone interview is often a first step of several in the hiring process, and sometimes you will be filtered out of the applicant pool.  The job announcement rarely tells the whole story of what people are looking for, or what criteria they hope they will find.

The important thing to remember when applying and interviewing for work is to remember it is a process, and you will get better with more interviewing practice.  It is also important to remember that just because you might be perfect for that job, that job may not be perfect for YOU.

I'd advise going on looking for other positions, and just let this play out.

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of things you can do:

```
A) Call right now and ask them along the lines of
   "Sorry, I didn't ask during the interview, but how long does a typical 
     candidate wait before receiving notification?"
B) Wait a standard 2 weeks to call and ask about your results:
   "I'm a candidate of position X. I haven't heard anything back for a while
    and wondering if you've made a decision on the position?"
```

Pros

```
A) Makes you feel confidence and control
   Gives you concrete expectations to work and plan around.
B) Gives the impression that you are patient.
```

Cons

```
A) May give a bad impression of impatience.
B) May give a sense of desperation.
```

You've probably already made a decision by the time you read this so I'll tell you what I would do. A). It gives you more control over your plans and it gets it out of the way so you don't have to dwell on it. The more uncomfortable it is to make that call, the better, because that will ingrain the next point into your mind.

In future interviews I would advise asking when to expect a reply. After that time has passed, it's safe to assume they will not call back.